# MySQL Query WHERE clause string comparison does not return results when it should

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly proficient in MySQL but I have never run into such an issue.

I have a record in the "node" table which is the following:

```
nid:     vid:     type:     lang:     title:
1        5        oa_group  und       CPA 2014 Actions
```

However when executing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `node` WHERE `title` = "CPA 2014 Actions"
```

the result set is 0. This record was imported through a CSV and for some reason, similar queries acted upon records NOT imported via CSV work fine.

Is there any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Don't you need simple quotes for strings, i.e. `title = 'CPA 2014 Actions'`?

Comment: Perhaps you have some blank space in there. Try `title LIKE '%CPA 2014 Actions%'`

Comment: Check the binary version. You might have a windows non-breaking space instead of normal space characters for example.

Comment: I did try the LIKE clause but that didn't work.
@fejese Can you be a little more clear on how to check the binary version? I'm not too sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! You were right @fejese. I just had to remove a nbsp character ubiquitous in every single imported record.